# Easyadmin Entity field multiple

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, easyadmin

Context : I want my users to be able to moderate my themes. I created a role moderator, and added a "moderation" (array) field to my user. Therefore, I can give rights to a specific user to one or more Themes.

I'm creating a Back Office to manage users using EasyAdmin & Symfony4.

I want to have a multiple select field displaying my available theme to give rights to users.

Here is my current configuration of easy admin :

```
User:
    class: App\Entity\User
    disabled_actions: ['new']
    edit:
        fields:
            - username
            - email
            - { property: 'roles', type: 'choice', type_options: { multiple: true, choices: { 'ROLE_USER': 'ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_MODERATOR': 'ROLE_MODERATOR', 'ROLE_ADMIN': 'ROLE_ADMIN' } } }
            - { property: 'moderate', type: 'entity', type_options: { class: 'App\Entity\Theme', multiple: true } }
```

Things are going pretty well, since I'm able to edit my user, give him a role, and give him sites to moderate.

The issue :
The current state of my "moderate" array is not displayed. The select doesn't have the current value displayed when showing up.